# How to cleanup JSON in Javascript after OpenAI GPT

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Im using OpenAI GPT4 to generate JSON as response and in Javascript i need to parse it using JSON.parse(json). Unfortunately AI does not escape special characters properly. It uses single backslash instead of double backslash. Here is example:

```
const badJson=`{
  "question": "When are you flying to \"Miami\"?\nPlease provide departure time."
}`
```

Proper JSON for JSON.parse() should be:

```
const goodJson=`{
  "question": "When are you flying to \\"Miami\\"?\\nPlease provide departure time."
}`
```

Any idea how to either convert badJson into goodJson or any JS library that can help parsing badJson?

Here is Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4rkg2h0q/

Comment: Uhh no you do not need double backslash characters

Comment: If you think that your backslash escapes need to be escaped, then you have something else going on in your code that is not clear from what is posted. In normal JSON string property values, a single backslash is all that is required.

Comment: If you're viewing the code with `JSON.stringify` or something, that's perfect behavior; the quotes will be rendered correctly as a string without the backslashes.

Comment: JSON.parse() requires double backslash in front of special chars. Try to feed badJson and goodJson to JSON.parse. It will error out on badJson.

Comment: The example you've given is JavaScript, not JSON. I find it hard to believe that the API you are using is outputting JavaScript source code instead of JSON. It looks like you've modified the output (with at least one manual step and probably also an automated one first) of the API which has introduced your problem. Please read [ask], provide a real [mcve].

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you want to write a better prompt to get properly quoted content? Do you want to know how to search and replace in a javascript string? Surely there's another question here that answers that already. As it stands, your question lacks focus.

Comment: @Quentin there is no API. If you real question it states that OpenAI generates this JSON. I cant make it generate proper JSON for Javascript so im looking for a solution programmatically. Gotta love those that dont bother understanding question and downvote it.

Comment: @AndreiV — Oh. So you're not using the OpenAPI GPT 4's API, you're trying to get OpenAPI GPT 4's GUI to write JavaScript with embedded JSON? Yikes.

Comment: @Christoph Basically I need to either find library that solves it or write extended or completely custom parser for this case. I am sure others who deal with GPT generating JSON facing same issues.

Comment: @Quentin not Javascript but just JSON in style of Javascript

Comment: Are you saying it **isn't** generating the const badJson=` section? If that's the case then the JSON it generates is valid and **you** are breaking it when transforming it into JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin I am simply asking it to return for me JSON that is parsable by the Javascript. Unfortunately badJson is text string that it returns. Technically it is valid json string but not for javascript JSON.parse() function. Thats reason im asking if anyone knows better parser for JS

Comment: The JSON it returns is valid (there's not need to use the word "technically" to imply that valid doesn't mean valid). The JSON it returns can be parsed by JSON.parse. What *can't* be parsed by JSON.parse is the string you get when you paste the JSON between two backticks in JavaScript source code because special characters in JSON are *also* special characters in JavaScript source code.

Comment: when JSON.parse() for the "valid" string fails thats invalid string in my books. I didnt write JSON.parse(). All questions to those guys. Either be helpful or please move on.

Comment: @AndreiV wouldn't replacing `\"` with `\\"` fix this? I doubt that there are libraries for that use case as the response from any LLM is not deterministic and there's no guarantee that all JSON-answers are formatted or escaped equally "wrong".

Comment: @christoph you absolutely correct that they all very fuzzy. Sometime it does generate it in format with //n and sometime it does not. I tried doing regular expressions to replace \n with \\n but since AI inserts new lines inside structure of the JSON itself (like after { ) it breaks JSON. Basically i need to find a way to replace \n with \\n only inside string values. Im also fine with any JS library that parses badJson string.

Comment: @AndreiV — "I didnt write JSON.parse()." — No, but you did write the JavaScript which defines the value that you pass to it.

Comment: @AndreiV — "Basically i need to find a way to replace \n with \\n only inside string values." – No, you don't. The string value you have doesn't have `\n` in it. The `\` characters are consumed by the JavaScript parser when it turns your template literal source code into a string

Comment: @Quentin try to take string badJson surrounded with either `` or '' or "". and then feed it to JSON.parse(badJson). It gives error. If you read on internet its common issue when ppl get string with single backslash escaped character and JSON.parse() fails. Regarding Javascript or JSON string itself. Its not generated by me. Thats what i get back from OpenAI call. Doesnt matter if I call OpenAI api or use ChatGPT. Im getting single backslash inside string.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `\` with `\\` in any text/code editor like VS Code (`STRG` +
`H`) or Notepad++?

Comment: When writing software to interact with an API, it is rarely practical to copy/paste the output of the API into a text editor for manual editing before copy/pasting it back into the software to continue automated processing.

Comment: @Georg Thank you for idea. I tried that but its tricky. I  need to replace all new lines with \\n only inside string values of the json. If JSON structure itself has new line (like in my example) then replacing those with //n will break JSON.

Comment: @Quentin I do agree with your opinion. However, this is not what Andrei asked for. In this case it's only for one by OpenApi generated JSON?

Comment: @AndreiV what you could also do is to ask OpenAPI to do the work for you?

Comment: I tried but its non deterministic. It sometime follows instruction and sometime not. So to cover my bases I decided to make parser that can accept both types of escaped characters. I would call first JSON.parse() and if it fails I will try parser that can handle \n instead of \\n